# как с помощью js или jQuery заменить данные таблицы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть таблица

```html
@foreach($param_default as $parameter)
                    <div class="row input_block">
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input name="print" type="checkbox" value="{{$parameter->print}}" {{$parameter->print == '1' ? 'checked' : ''}} class="field check print" style="width: 100%;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <input name="inspection" type="text" value="{{$parameter->inspection}}" class="field inspection" style="width: 100%;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input name="method" type="text" value="{{$parameter->method}}" class="field method" style="width: 100%;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input name="result" type="text" value="{{$parameter->result}}" class="field result" style="width: 100%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
```

далее ajax ом получаю массив этих данных

```js
$.ajax({

                    type:'POST',
                    url:'/ajaxRequestParameter/show',
                    data:{
                        "product_id":product_id,
                        "category_id":category_id
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                    //data это массив с данными для обновления таблицы
                        var cl = $('.input_block').filter( ':first' ).clone(true);
                        
                    }

                   });
```

Comment: и дальше то где код? строку продублировали, замените в ней данные, добавьте к таблице

Comment: ну дальше нет это что я предпологал продублировать правильно?)